# word press landing page created issue

Tags: wordpress

Actually  Im beginner for a `word press` I want to know how to create word press  landing page for  this type,example  some one click  the English button after need to open  English page,(Im already do that all of page) but I cant make this type landing page, anyone know how to do that correctly

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate your question, it does not make sense.

Comment: Read this about theming and templates hierarchy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

For landing page please check below

```
Go to Appearance->Customize->staticFont Page

here you can find option for landing page
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) will give you a comprehensive answer.

Essentially in the settings menu goto the reading menu, select static page and choose your page in the homepage dropdown. Update then it'll be set as the homepage.

[image]